# scattering effect

Tags: iphone

I went through all my resources but I am not getting the scattering effect of an image smoothly. However, I am able to zoom it and I had scattered it but it is not as smooth as I want. I just want to click on a button and it should zoom and the other image should get scatter

I want the image to be scattered as the link given below is it possible in iPhone?
http://www.touchmagix.com/templates/diamond.htm

Answer (score 0):

this is hell lot of graphics. If you intend to achieve this with iPhone sdk, start learning details about CALayer and then try to manipulate the movements of different objects. Which will require lot of coding logic. 
My suggestion would be going for Cocos2D and try with the different classes and api's present there. In Cocos2D you can create an image which will act as an actual physical object and you can apply all laws of physics to it. Say if you create a ball, and you push it, the ball will go in the direction of the push and bounce back if it gets hit by any other physical object and you don't require to do any coding for this. Cocos2D takes care of all these things. 
Try it.